# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.ssh’: Permission denied when ssh-copy-id

Tags: ssh

```
┌─╼ [~/Downloads]
└╼ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 my_username@server
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/infinity/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
my_username@server's password: 
Could not chdir to home directory /gel/usr/my_username: No such file or directory
sh: line 0: cd: /gel/usr/my_username: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.ssh’: Permission denied
```

I connect on the server, but it is impossible to create the directory `my_username` in `/gel/usr`. Is there a workaround to fix this issue? Can I modify $PATH in some ways in the server to fix that up?

Comment: Sounds like your home directory in `/etc/passwd` is invalid on that machine. Need to have a home directory to drop a copy of your keys into...

Comment: Either invalid home as Aaron says, or missing write permissions in your home directory.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco There is no workaround for that, right?

Comment: There are suggestions in the answers. If you aren't the admin on the remote machine, it's that machine's IT's problem...

Answer (score 2):

There is no home directory located at that location, as indicated by the error line

```
Could not chdir to home directory /gel/usr/my_username: No such file or directory
```

Usually home directories are located in `/home/`, for example `/home/username`.

You can either edit the `/etc/passwd` file directly and input a proper, preexisting path, or you can utilize the `usermod` command to change the home directory as follows:

`usermod -d /home/username username`

You will need to change the instances of username to match your situation.